# Android, use/don wake locks when receiving a message from GCM and want to do work outside the onReceive, if the device is in deep sleep mode?

Tags: android, locks

I am developing an application in which I have

- a Service, that does http requests and writes data to db
- a receiver declared in manifest, that listens for GCM messages
- a receiver, declared in code ( in the Service ), used to "talk" to the service

Each time I am receiving a GCM message I want extract the data from the intent, and broadcast it to the service. The service will then query an http server, get the response and insert data into db.

Now, I am afraid that, if the phone is in deep sleep, the phone will be wake just until the GCM onReceive executes and not until my Service does work. Here is my GCM receiver onReceive:

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    String url = extractUrl(intent.getExtras());

    Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(context, MyService.class);
    serviceIntent.setAction(MyService.ACTION_DO_WORK);
    Bundle data = new Bundle();
    data.putString(MyService.URL_KEY, url);
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(context).sendBroadcast(serviceIntent);
}
```

I have the feeling I have to use a CPU lock ( correct me if I'm mistakeing )

Where should I acquire the partial wake lock? Should I acquire it here and then release it in my Service, after he does the work? ( is it safe to acquire the lock in one place and release it in other one )

Thanks,

Comment: I think you're right; it's similar to receiving a message from [AlarmManager -- check the second paragraph under the docs for that](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html); it describes using exactly the strategy you're suggesting to protect yourself from the phone sleeping before your service does anything.

Comment: Hi Matt, I am having problems because I don't know if I should get the lock in the Service. Maybe Android will resume sleeping asap as the onReceive is done, so the delivering the message to the service will never occur. If so, I may have to acquire the lock in GCM onReceive and release it in Service. Though, I don't know if this is correct, not how to do it since you obtain a new instance of WakeLock each time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Where should I acquire the partial wake lock?

Ideally, you let some tested code do that, by using [`WakefulBroadcastReceiver`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/WakefulBroadcastReceiver.html) or [my `WakefulIntentService`](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-wakeful).

Both of those will acquire the `WakeLock` during the call to `onReceive()` and will arrange to release the `WakeLock` when your `IntentService` completes its work.

Comment: Hi, unfortunately my service is started by an activity and it will run in the background ( START_STCIKY ). So it will not be started from the receiver. As you can see the receiver will send a message to the service and that's it. How can assure that the service will complete it's work before the Android will go to sleep again, in this situation of mine?

Comment: @user3030447: "How can assure that the service will complete it's work before the Android will go to sleep again" -- it sounds like you are trying to have your service run all of the time, which is an anti-pattern on Android. Beyond that, if you do not like `WakefulIntentService` and `WakefulBroadcastReceiver`, you are welcome to examine their code to see how they handle the `WakeLock`, so you can determine how best to adapt it to your scenario.

Comment: WhatsApp use a running service... I mean I don't see what's wrong with having a restartable service running all the time... I am coding a chat client btw :)

Comment: Nevertheless, a static WakeLock I guess could do the job :). Thanks for the code.